# Jquery condition check for multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html

I want a jquery function in which i can check whether how many checkboxes have been checked by using checkbox name since all checkbox have same name and get the values all together..

```
<input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Php">
<input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Java">
<input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Jquery">
<input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Jscript">
<input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Clanguage">
```

I want wantever checked values at once..Please help..

Comment: Have you considered having each checkbox with a different name so, on top of having how many checkboxes have been checked, you also have which ones where?

Answer (score 3):

You can

```
//get all the checked inputs with name skills
var checked = $('input[name="skills"]:checked');
//number of checked items
var checkedlength = checked.length;
//an array containing values of all checked inputs
var values = checked.map(function(){
    return this.value
}).get();
```

Comment: Very nice approach :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function

```
var vals = $.map($('input[name="skills"]:checked').get(), function(i){
    return i.value;
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/S6hxY/1/)

Or, this (as Arun P Johny did but, with less code, within one line)

```
var vals = $('input[name="skills"]:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value
}).get();
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/S6hxY/)

Or, as a comma seperated string

```
var values = $('input[name="skills"]:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value
}).get().join();
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/S6hxY/2/)